# Git Edit Config File on Mac

Tags: git

I am trying to remove URL's that are in my git global config file and have read to just edit the file in the terminal. How I only see ways on windows to edit it?

```
git config --global --edit
```

Pulls up the info but how to edit it on a mac in the terminal?

Comment: I suppose `vim ~/.gitconfig` is not an option?

Comment: @CoryKramer I can view it either way. What keys are needed to edit? I cannot edit anything. on windows i found hitting insert first to edit but this is not the case for the mac.

Comment: If you are not comfortable using `vim` then instead `open -e ~./gitconfig` to use the text editor of your choice

Comment: that did nothing except the file does not exist. I have not used a mac long so i am somewhat unfamiliar with certain things compare to a PC.

Comment: got it. D or dd to remove. This is what I was looking for when in edit mode..

Comment: So, is your question "how do I operate vim" rather than "how do I get Git to use the editor of my choice"?

Comment: I never asked how to get it to work with an editor of my choice. I asked how to edit through the terminal. Cory Kramer suggested vim. Searching for vim I found shortcuts to delete lines and edit it. My searches to edit using the normal git edit in the terminal were harder to find then vim was, but seems those commands are similar either way. So he somewhat helped me find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in this link below:-

[How to configure default editor for GIT in various Operating Systems.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C%3A-Git-Commands-Setup-and-Config)

They have specified various editors like `TextEdit` in `macOS`, `NotePad++` in `Windows`, and `Sublime` for `Ubantu`.

If the editors are configured in your System's Environment Variables, it will be easier to set it up, for this is the command-line option :- `[shell (Bourne, Korn) or zsh or DOS]`.

Check this with the following commands (mac OS) :-

```
$ git config --global core.editor "open --wait-apps --new -e"
$ git commit -a
```